# iOSの開発において、Swiftのバージョン指定が効かない

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

### 前提

iOS のアプリを開発しております。

---

### 発生している問題

Swift 4.2 でビルドされた Framework を追加して、プロジェクト＆ターゲット設定の
Swift Language Version も、 Swift 4.2 に設定しているのですが、特定の Framework が、

> Module compiled with Swift 4.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.0 compiler:

といったエラーを吐きます。

Swift のバージョンを 4.2 と指定しているにも関わらず、 Swift 5.0 でビルドしているようです。

Swift 4.2 でビルドするには、どうすればよろしいのでしょうか。
宜しくお願いいたします。

---

### 補足情報 (OS, ツールのバージョンなど)

#### 開発環境

- OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.4（18E226）
- Xcode: Version 10.2 (10E125)

Comment: Swift 5コンパイラのSwift 4.2モードでコンパイルされたバイナリーにSwift 4.2コンパイラでコンパイルされたバイナリーをリンクすることはできません。FrameworkをSwift 5コンパイラでビルドし直すか、Swift 4.2コンパイラの付属するXcode 10.1を入手する必要があります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！Xcode10.1を導入しましたら、上手く行きました。